# How do I include a PHP variable in a URL string?

Tags: php, iframe

I'm trying to put an iFrame into a User Profile page, and that iFrame will pull in info from a SECOND User Profile page (same User, different parts of their profile).

My PHP skills are awful, but here's where I'm at:

**`<iframe src="http://www.example.co.uk/profile/?uu_username=<?php echo`$user_id ?>" width="1000" height="700">`**

...where I'm trying to pass the User ID to the end of the URL, so that it will read this:

**`http://www.example.co.uk/profile/?uu_username=29`**

So I'm pretty sure the variable works right as I've had that working elsewhere - I know it's by bad PHP syntax.  Excuse the mess of code it probably looked better an hour ago!

Can someone please help?

Comment: What is your question? Your code is correct.

Comment: That looks like it should technically work to me. What error are you getting? Also, you may want to change to the following syntax: echo "<iframe src=\"http://www.example.co.uk/profile/?uu_username=$user_id\" width=\"1000\" height=\"700\">";

Comment: It is correct but you are missing a ; at <?php echo $user_id;?>

Comment: @embe, it's not required

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into my answer... I got a strange character between echo and $user_id. Is that causing your issue?

Comment: if you are trying to put the "uu_username" value from URL into the iframe you have to do: <iframe src="http://www.example.co.uk/profile/uu_username=<?php echo $_GET['uu_username'] ?>" width="1000" height="700"> ... WARNING: the code I just posted is vulnerable to XSS (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)

Comment: The error I'm getting is that the URL opened into the iFrame is everything I want, minus the '29'.  So I was thinking the PHP mist be wrong, but if it's right, there must be a different issue?